Python integration on C++ Builder as CLI command
I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder to create a file encryption project based on Argon2 and AES-256 with 500,000 iterations. I decided to develop everything in Python; the Python file, named AEScrypt, is located in the same directory as the .exe compiled by C++ Builder and works perfectly. It operates like this:
python AEScrypt.py password FilePath <encrypt/decrypt>

If I use just the Python file, it works perfectly in every way. However, what I thought would be a simple task — implementing a C++ program that would only take the path from OpenDialog in Edit1 and the password in Edit2 — has turned into a nightmare.
I previously sought help from ChatGPT, but as usual, it was unhelpful. I simply cannot call this file with the parameters. There are two buttons: Button1 for Encryption and Button2 for Decryption. The program works as follows: it encrypts and generates a .aes file, for example, image1.png becomes image1.png.aes. It keeps the original file and generates the .aes file in the same directory as the original file. The program only encrypts one file at a time, which is selected by the user. I tried: CreateProcess(), WinExec(), System(), and more complex approaches, but it always results in an error, either with reading, nothing happening, or an error stating that the Python file cannot be read even though it's in the same folder, or it reads but doesn't encrypt. Can anyone help me?
I am using Windows 11 and C++ Builder 12. I just need a function that passes these parameters correctly as mentioned above and verifies if the .aes file was generated in the directory where the selected file is located. The rest is ready, including the interface and other functions. The Python file is error-free; I tested it numerous times, and it works fine via CMD. The issue lies with C++ when calling it. also I am compiling in a 64-bits architecture. Why the python is working fine but the C++ can't call it correctly. I just need the function that I implement the rest. I didn't paste it here because I deleted everything and will try to build again. Maybe could be something about the Path that I couldn't understand... The OpenDialog returns to Edit1->Text="C:\Administrador\Documentos\image1.jpg" and the password could be numbers, letters and alphanumeric.
Anyway, if you want to see, this is my Python code AEScrypt.py:
import sys
import os
import hashlib
import base64
import secrets
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from argon2 import PasswordHasher

def generate_key(password):
    password = password[::-1]
    ph = PasswordHasher()
    hashed_password = ph.hash(password)
    salt = hashed_password.split('$')[3] 
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), base64.b64decode(salt), 500000, dklen=32)
    return key

def encrypt_file(file_path, password):
    key = generate_key(password)
    iv = secrets.token_bytes(16)  
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
        padded_data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
        encrypted_data = encryptor.update(padded_data) + encryptor.finalize()

    encrypted_file_path = file_path + '.aes'
    with open(encrypted_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(iv + encrypted_data)  

def decrypt_file(file_path, password):
    key = generate_key(password)
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        iv = f.read(16)  # Lê o IV do início do arquivo
        data = f.read()

    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    decrypted_data = decryptor.update(data) + decryptor.finalize()
    unpadder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()
    data = unpadder.update(decrypted_data) + unpadder.finalize()

    decrypted_file_path = file_path.replace('.aes', '')
    with open(decrypted_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print("Usage: AEScrypt.py <password> <file> <encrypt|decrypt>")
        sys.exit(1)

    password = sys.argv[1]
    file_path = sys.argv[2]
    
    # Verificar se o caminho é absoluto
    if not os.path.isabs(file_path):
        print("Error: The file path must be absolute.")
        sys.exit(1)

    action = sys.argv[3]

    if action == 'encrypt':
        encrypt_file(file_path, password)
        print(f"File encrypted and saved to {file_path}.aes")
    elif action == 'decrypt':
        decrypt_file(file_path, password)
        print(f"File decrypted and saved to {file_path.replace('.aes', '')}")
    else:
        print("Invalid action. Use 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'.")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I tried more than 5 ways to call the python file and pass the parameters. As string, Unicode, Ansistring. Nothing worked.
Here is the C++ code I tried:
void __fastcall TForm3::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    
    if (Edit1->Text.IsEmpty() || Edit2->Text.IsEmpty()) {
        ShowMessage("Por favor, preencha o caminho do arquivo e a senha.");
        return;
    }

    String filePath = ExpandFileName(Edit1->Text);  
    String password = Edit2->Text;

    
    String command = "cmd /C python AEScrypt.py \"" + password + "\" \"" + filePath + "\" encrypt";

    
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;  

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    
    if (CreateProcess(NULL, command.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) 
    {
        
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    } 
    else 
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        String errorMsg = "Erro ao executar o script Python. Código do erro: " + IntToStr(dwError);
        ShowMessage(errorMsg);
    }
}


If the problem is with the C++ code, maybe you should show that. Are you capturing STDOUT and STDERR from the Python exe to see what it is reporting?

Why not write the gui in python too ? Python usually ships with tkinter out of the box

@AhmedAEK I wish I could. It would be a demonstration of Python and C++ working together. And

@001 There's no return. The python file do all the work. I don't need the stdout or stderr from it. Just call and passes the arguments. I am running the python console in SW_HIDE

My point was: what if it is throwing an exception? The info provided in the stack trace can help you.

@001 The C++ program return success but the task is not complete. I rewrite this python file 6 times to treat exceptions. On the CMD it works like a charm, when I call it on C++ nothing happens.

"... AES-256 with 500,000 iterations..." you might want to research this, but last time I looked into multiple iterations of AES, there was no available proof that 500,000 iterations was not equivalent to 1 iteration with a different key.

@RichardCritten I was copying Veracrypt....

You are getting an error in your c++ code but you are showing the python code ... you should've shown the c++ code

@AhmedAEK It's pointless because my code is obviously very wrong, but I posted.
